# Sorting in alphabetical order from a file in python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.3

Help me this is my current code

```
p=('class1.txt')
file=open(p,'r')
d=file.read()
print(d)
with open('Class1.txt', 'r') as f:
    Class1=sorted(Class1.rstrip('\n') for Class1 in f)
print(Class1)
q=('class2.txt')
file=open(q,'r')
f=file.read()
print(f)

w=('class3.txt')
file=open(w,'r')
g=file.read()
print(g)
```

I am trying to sort from a text file called Class1.txt i am also trying to make it in highest to lowest from the numbers

Comment: What is wrong with the current code? Do you get any errors?

Comment: What does `Class1.txt` look like?

Answer (score 0):

If the lines are all ints you need to convert to int and reverse the sort:

```
with open('Class1.txt', 'r') as f:
    class_1 = sorted((int(i) for i  in f),reverse=True)
    print(class_1)
```

If you don't cast to int then `"22" > "100"`

Comment: generator expression error and it highlights nothing

Comment: @bobabu, missed the inner parens

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
   programs\test3.py", line 7, in <module>
    sorted((int(i) for i in f),reverse=True)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: then you are not doing it inside the with statement.

Comment: can you please explain what you mean

Comment: @bobabu, are you running the code exactly as I have in my answer?

Comment: File "H:\computing \practice programs\test3.py", line 6, in <module>
    class_1 = sorted((int(i) for i  in f),reverse=True)
  File "H:\computing \practice programs\test3.py", line 6, in <genexpr>
    class_1 = sorted((int(i) for i  in f),reverse=True)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'q1,w4,e6,t8,y,10,u2,i5,o3,p7'

Comment: ok well we cannot make an int of out that, what do you want to sort by you have digits and letters and a mixture of both